# Общие типы для сервера и клиента на TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript

Разрабатываю проект где сервер и клиент пишу на TypeScript. Можно ли как-то написать общие тайпинги для проекта? Например, чтобы можно было использовать один и тот же интерфейс и на сервере, и на клиенте.

Comment: Непонятно что мешает это сделать.

Comment: @AlexeyTen допустим, я объявляю `interfaces.d.ts` и пытаюсь его импортировать в entry-файле сервера и клиента. `export declare global {}` делать нельзя. `export {} declare global {}` тоже нельзя. В итоге, в каждый отдельный модуль нужно прописывать `import * from '../interfaces.d.ts'`

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю вопрос в общей организации общего кода.

Можно сделать по этому примеру:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53428140/2871225

Или более наворочено: делать свои приватные npm-пакеты, юзать другие специализированные инструменты. Много описано тут: 
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/04/sharing-code-between-projects/

Вообще все зависит от Ваших потребностей. Не стоит прибегать к сложным инфраструктурным решениям если они и вправду не нужны. Например, не вижу ничего прям криминального если общий код будет валяться в отдельном репозитории а другие проекты будут тупо импортить их вот так на прямую:

```
import { SomeSharedClass } from "../../SomeSharedProject/src/index"
```

Немножко страшно, но работает. При надобности всегда можно перейти на более "правильное" решение.